# Vector subscript mismatch with odeint (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, odeint

I am implementing ODE to solve for four coupled equations, and am running into issue with the definition of my state vector. I am following the example here for reference (https://www.codeproject.com/articles/268589/odeint-v-solving-ordinary-differential-equations); as I said the only difference between my code and this one is the actual definition of the equations, and that I need a vector with 4 elements, instead of 3.

My code is as follows (the values of mass, inertia, etc. defined in the equations is based on user input from another class); I have not yet added an observer to push-back the results, as I want to get this working first.
Vector state definition:

```
typedef std::vector< double >state_type;
```

Coupled ODE class:

```
class coupledODE : public Vehicle, public Road
{
    public:
        void operator()(state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, double t)
        {
            dxdt[0] = x[2];
            dxdt[1] = (1 / mass)*(-(damping_f + damping_r)*x[2] - (stiffness_f + stiffness_r)*x[1] - (damping_r*rearLength - damping_f*frontLength)*x[4] - (stiffness_r*rearLength - stiffness_f*frontLength)*x[3] + stiffness_f*A*sin((radFreq)*t) + stiffness_r*A*sin((radFreq)*t - (2 * pi*(frontLength + rearLength)) / L));
            dxdt[3] = x[4];
            dxdt[4] = (1 / inertia)*(-(damping_f*pow(frontLength, 2) + damping_r*pow(rearLength, 2))*x[4] - (stiffness_f*pow(frontLength, 2) + stiffness_r*pow(rearLength, 2))*x[3] - (stiffness_r*rearLength - stiffness_f*frontLength)*x[2] - (stiffness_r*rearLength - stiffness_f*frontLength)*x[1] + stiffness_r*rearLength*A*sin((radFreq)*t - (2 * pi*(rearLength + frontLength)) / L) - stiffness_f*frontLength*A*sin((radFreq)*t));
        }
};
```

Call in main:

```
state_type x(4);
x[0] = car.x_init1;
x[1] = car.x_init2;
x[2] = car.x_init3;
x[3] = car.x_init4;

const double timeStep = car.dt;
double tStart = car.t0;
double t = tStart;
double tEnd = car.tf;

// Initialize odeint
runge_kutta4<state_type>rk4;
for (size_t i = 0; i < (tStart - tEnd) / timeStep; ++i, t += timeStep)
{
    rk4.do_step(coupledODE(), x, t, timeStep);
}
```

The code compiles fine when I build it in MSVS '15, but when I run it, I get an exception at the line defining the initial value of `x[3]`. This exact format works fine for 3 coupled equations, so I'm at a bit of a loss for what's causing an issue with the fourth element.

Comment: Unclear. This is the problematic line: `x[4] = car.x_init4;`?

Comment: Yes, but it should be 'x[3]'. I have corrected that but still am receiving the subscript error.

Comment: Dang. So much for the easy problem. Nothing obvious left. Have to ask for a [mcve]. That said, if you put a breakpoint on `x[3] = car.x_init4;` and step in when the program hits the breakpoint you may get more useful information.

Comment: I figured it out. The new error is coming from the fact that when I ported the ODEs from MATLAB, the states were defined as x[1]-x[4] (the equations in the ODE class body). Here they need to be defined as x[0]-x[3].

Comment: Nice of Microsoft to give you the subscript error. All the C++ standard guarantees is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Error due to subscript in actual ODE eqtns - must start at x[0] and end at x[3]. Error has been solved by modifying the equations